# How to compare the output of a function with a value on screen?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a java function that returns current date.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = new Date();    
System.out.println("Current Date: "+dateFormat.format(date));
```

Using selenium web driver I want to compare the output of above function with the date displayed on the U.I.

How can this be done?

Comment: Where does the date on the UI come from? you need to find that out first and then think how your this code can access that and then compare them

Comment: Hi try the selenium with junit. You can capture the date from UI using selenium and validate against the date come from the api in junit test case.

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium Webdriver you can use `getText()` to get date from UI and store it in a variable. The above `dateFormat.format(date)` can also be stored in a variable. Now all that you have to do is compare both the variables by using the methods provided by `Java`.